Uniform Convergence of Empirical Means: Universal Separability Implies Measurability
On page 38 of Pollard's book "Convergence of Stochastic Processes" one finds the following exercise (Problem 3 in Chapter II):
Call a class of functions $\mathcal{F}$ universally separable if there exists a countable subclass $\mathcal{F}_0$ such that each $f$ in $\mathcal{F}$ can be written as a pointwise limit of a sequence in $\mathcal{F}_0$. If $\mathcal{F}$ has an envelope $F$ for which $PF<\infty$, prove that universal separability implies measurability of $\lVert P_n-P\rVert$.
Notes:

$P$ is a probability measure on a set $S$ resp. on a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma\subseteq\mathcal{P}(S)$.
$\mathcal{F}$ is a set of (measurable) functions mapping from $S$ into $\mathbb{R}$.
$P_n$ is the empirical probability measure that puts equal mass at each of the $n$ observations $\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n$. More precisely: $$P_nf=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n f(\xi_i)$$ for $f\in\mathcal{F}$.
$Pf$ denotes the expected value of $P_nf$ (if $Pf<\infty$).
$\lVert P_n-P\rVert:=\sup\limits_{f\in\mathcal{F}}|P_nf-Pf|$.
An envelope $F$ for $\mathcal{F}$ is a measurable map $F\colon S\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $|f|\leq F$ for any $f\in\mathcal{F}$.

I personally am mostly interested in the case when $\mathcal{F}$ is a set of characteristic functions, i.e. functions whose image is a subset of {0,1}. In this case, $\mathcal{F}$ is universally separable, as witnessed by the countable subclass $\mathcal{F}_0$, if for any $f\in\mathcal{F}$ there exists a sequence $(f_n)_n$ in $\mathcal{F}_0$ such that for any $s\in S$ there exists $n_s\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(s)=f_n(s)$ for any $n\geq n_s$. Moreover, in my setting, I usually assume that $S$ is a topological space and $\Sigma$ is the corresponding Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by the topology.
My attempts so far:

First note that $P_n$ depends on $\underline{\xi}=(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n)$. Therefore, I denote by $P_n(\underline{\xi})f$ the empirical mean $$\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n f(\xi_i).$$ Further, we have $$Pf=\mathbb{E}_{\underline{\xi}\sim P^n}[P_n(\underline{\xi})f]=\mathbb{E}_{\xi\sim P}[f(\xi)],$$ where $P^n$ denotes the product measure $P\otimes\dots\otimes P$.
The map $$\lVert P_n-P\rVert\colon S^n\to\mathbb{R},\ \underline{\xi}\mapsto\sup\limits_{f\in\mathcal{F}}|P_n(\underline{\xi})f-Pf|$$ is measurable if for any $\varepsilon>0$ the set {$\underline{\xi}=(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n)\in S^n\mid \lVert P_n(\underline{\xi})-P\rVert\leq\varepsilon$} is a member of the product $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma^n=\Sigma\otimes\dots\otimes\Sigma$.
I suppose that the idea is to show that $$\sup\limits_{f\in\mathcal{F}}|P_n(\underline{\xi})(f)-Pf|=\sup\limits_{f\in\mathcal{F}_0}|P_n(\underline{\xi})(f)-Pf|.$$ However, I don't see how one can show this. Given $f\in\mathcal{F}$ and $\underline{\xi}\in S^n$, the universal separability of $\mathcal{F}$ implies that there exists $f_0\in\mathcal{F}_0$ such that $P_n(\underline{\xi})f=P_n(\underline{\xi})f_0$. However, I don't see how the subclass $\mathcal{F}_0$ can be used with regard to $Pf$.

I'm looking forward to comments and answers! Please let me know if I shall clarify some point.

In the meantime, I have figured out how one can prove the above statement. Essentially, one exploits the fact that if the sequence f_n converges pointwise to f, then also the empirical means converge pointwise to the empirical mean of the limit and the expected values converge to the expected value of the limit. The latter can be shown by applying the Dominated Convergence Theorem (this also explains why one assumes that there exists a so-called envelope for the function class). Exploiting these convergences, one can show the equality in the last bullet point.

In the meantime, I have figured out how one can prove the above statement. Essentially, one exploits the fact that if the sequence $(f_m)_{m}$ converges pointwise to $f$, then also the empirical means $P_nf_m$ converge pointwise to the empirical mean of the limit $P_nf$ and the expected values $Pf_m$ converge to the expected value of the limit $Pf$. The latter convergence can be proved by applying the Dominated Convergence Theorem (this also explains why one assumes the existence of a so-called envelope for the function class, as this is one of the hypotheses of the theorem). Exploiting these convergences, one can show that $$\sup\limits_{f\in\mathcal{F}}|P_nf-Pf|=\sup\limits_{f\in\mathcal{F}_0}|P_nf-Pf|.$$ The countability of $\mathcal{F}_0$ then implies the measurability, since the supremum of a countable family of measurable functions is again measurable.
